# Which one is: "REAR LATERAL ROD BUSHING - FRONT (INNER)"

Tags: suspension, bushing, rear, rod

[image]
I think it's the top one of the 48730A arm, but not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would be of huge assistance if you gave us the year/make/model of the vehicle in question.

Comment: Why hide the picture? That is what I based my answer on to help you...

Answer (score 1):

The inner will be the end of the arm 48730A with the bushing 48409 and bolt 48703E.

Not sure of your use of "top", but the inner bushing is what I have described.